# USING OF SUBQUERY

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

below is database and table details.
database name - mis_v1
table 1 name - trips
table 2 name - client

i tried below queries

Query 1

```
select cl.client_name CLIENT
     , count(t.trip_type) TRIPS
     , count(distinct t.vehicle_reg_no) VEHICLES
  from mis_v1.trips t
  JOIN mis_v1.client cl 
    ON cl.id = t.client_id 
 group 
    by cl.client_name;
```

Query 1 result

```
CLIENT      TRIPS   VEHICLES
anz-ABlr    118     16  
citrix-CBlr 159     15  
dxc-DBlr    26      5   
Eps-Blr     116     24  
goc-GocHyd  191     10
Unisys-BLR  192     55
Wipro-Ncr   86      33
Wipro-Pnq   10      5
```

Query 2

```
select cl.client_name CLIENT
     , count(t.trip_delay_reason) LATE_TRIPS
  FROM mis_v1.trips t
  JOIN mis_v1.client cl 
    ON cl.id = t.client_id
 where t.trip_delay_reason = "DRIVER"
 group 
    by cl.client_name;
```

Query 2 result

```
CLIENT       LATE_TRIPS
anz-ABlr        53
citrix-CBlr     25
dxc-DBlr        1
Wipro-Ncr       1
goc-GocHyd      17
```

I need result as below

```
CLIENT     TRIPS    VEHICLES    LATE_TRIPS
anz-ABlr    118     16          53
citrix-CBlr 159     15          25
dxc-DBlr    26      5           1
Eps-Blr     116     24          -
goc-GocHyd  191     10          17
Unisys-BLR  192     55          -
Wipro-Ncr   86      33          1
Wipro-Pnq   10      5           -
```

Kindly give me solution.Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
select cl.client_name CLIENT
     , count(t.trip_type) TRIPS
     , count(distinct t.vehicle_reg_no) VEHICLES
     , coalesce(cast(count(case when t.trip_delay_reason = "DRIVER" then 1 else null end) as char), '-') LATE_TRIPS
from mis_v1.trips t
JOIN mis_v1.client cl 
  ON cl.id = t.client_id 
group 
  by cl.client_name;
```

So, please read more about **COUNT** aggreagate function and probably **CASE** operator

Comment: The above code is useful and has served my purpose.

Comment: Hi! Please accept the answer, if it resolved your query. Otherwise, your question is still considered unanswered.